# What method(s) do I use in order to get the following function in its geometric series form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It follows that I want to write the Maclaurin series (which is unique for a given function iff the function is analytic in a given ball of center 0, radius $= |z_0-z_s|$; $z_0=0$ being the point of expansion and $z_s$ the closest singularity of $f(z)$).

In order to get that same Maclaurin series, one has to extract from $f(z)$ the function which describes the famous geometric series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(ax^n) := 1/(1-x)$; $a$ = constant and $|x|$ smaller then 1.

[I want to find the Maclaurin series for the following funtion;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1t2v.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please write out the function – not everyone likes to chase links. There are tips in the help menu on formatting mathematics on this site. Also, you're expected to show that you know something about Maclaurin series, and where you get stuck applying what you know to this particular problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  We hope you enjoy and we also recommend that you take a look at the [Mathjax handbook](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

Differentiate once and you get

$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

Let $x=-z^2:$

$$\frac1{(1+z^2)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}nz^{2n-2}$$

Thus multiply both sides by $-2z$

$$\frac{-2z}{(1+z^2)^2}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nnz^{2n-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much I edited my answer, so people don't think I know nothing.